# Floyds Triangle as a method

Tags: c#, methods

How can I put my code into a method to work because now it has an error and I can't figure out how to solve it. In our exam we have to put every exercise into a method but now it says 'Cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'string' when i try to return it (the 'n' is underlined).

```
    public string FloydsTriangle(int n)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = num; i > 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = num; j >= i; j--)
            {
                Console.Write(count + " ");
                count++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        return n;
    }
```

Comment: Your method return string and you are returning int.

Comment: Well.  You pass in `n` which is an `int` and you're return type is a `string` (`public **string** FloydsTriangle).  The return type needs to be `int` (or return nothing, `void`) or you need to return a `string`.

Comment: Your method says it returns a string but you return `n` which is an integer.  Simplest thing to do is make the function void and remove the `n` argument as you don't use it.

Comment: But I wanna use it so e.g. if i type Console.WriteLine(n); it should show me the floyds triangle.

Comment: Why does this method return a `string`? And why does it accept an `int` parameter when you don't do anything with it? Perhaps instead of prompting the user for a number inside this method, you should just work with the `int n` that is passed to this method. And perhaps instead of writing the characters to the console inside this method, the string representation should be returned?

Comment: Sure.  You can do that.  You can't return an `int` when the declared return type for the method is a `string`

Comment: What are you trying to actually return from this method? Why are you returning 'n' when you do nothing to it between input and return?

Comment: Tbh im not sure. All i know is that the exercise is that we should write a code for Floyds Triangle. The teacher said that we can do it in the Main part but then put it in the method which is given like this:         public string FloydsTriangle(int n)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code doesn't make a lot of sense, since you have a method which takes in an `int`, but does nothing with it, and returns a `string`, which is just the same `int` the user passed in only converted to a string (assuming you add `.ToString()` to the return value as mentioned in the other answer).

One idea to make this work would be to use the `int` argument as the basis for the triangle, and then to return a string representation of the triangle (instead of reading or writing anything to the console inside this method).

Note, I did not correct any of your existing code - I only changed how the method uses the input parameter and how it outputs the result:

```
public static string GetFloydsTriangle(int n)
{
    int count = 1;

    // Instead of writing strings to the console, we'll
    // store them in this string and return it at the end
    string triangle = string.Empty;

    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = n; j >= i; j--)
        {
            triangle = triangle + count + " ";
            count++;
        }

        triangle = triangle + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    return triangle;
}
```

Then, to use the method, we will ask the user for a number in the `Main` method, then pass that to our method. Additionally, we'll capture the return value from the triangle method (which is our triangle string), and write that string to the console in the `Main` method.

This is a pretty standard way to write a helper method - it just does some calculations based on input data and returns a result (it doesn't interact with the user or UI).

Again, I am not correcting your code, only refactoring it to use the new method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    string triangle = GetFloydsTriangle(num);
    Console.WriteLine(triangle);

    Console.Write("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method specifies that you'll be passing back a `string`. You'll want to do something like:

```
return n.toString();
```

Otherwise you'll need to change your method to:

```
public int FloydsTriangle(int n)
```

Comment: Thanks, the return n.ToString(); works. Now how can I use this method? Because if I type 'n' in the Main window or whatever its called it shows an error. (Sorry im a noob.)

Comment: You'll want to call it from your main by defining an integer as the method... something like: int x = FloydsTriangle();              ... alternatively, you could always change the whole method to a void and just remove the return.

Comment: The problem you're going to have is that you'll never want to call x from your main for any real reason. All of the work is actually done within your FloydsTriangle method, thus you'll want to just call that method. I'd recommend changing the method to a void and removing the return statement. This will allow you to simply call it from anywhere in your main by putting "FloydsTriangle();".

Comment: If i do that this is what happens: https://gyazo.com/cc28db1a542e2107f8facef63f876752

Comment: When you call it as a void you'll want to just call it from your main as: FloydsTriangle(); and then when you define the method it'll just be: public static void FloydsTriangle(){ .... otherwise you'll need to pass a variable, which you're not

Comment: Public static void FloydsTriangle(){... not public void FloydsTriangle(){

Comment: the Series05 is still underlined and it says 'Program' does not implement interface member 'Series05.FloydsTriangle(int)'

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!